# Setting up single drive storage space for future two way mirror

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, storage-spaces

I am setting up a storage space that initially will only be a single drive but I eventually will add additional drives and transition to two way mirror.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a method for me to be able to add the second drive at a later date (and take advantage of 2 way mirroring) without needing to reformat the initial drive.

Comment: Do you mean RAID? If so, please post which type. If not, please describe what you mean by "2 way mirroring".

Comment: I guess it uses a built in form of RAID. I was using the terminology that Windows itself uses just to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @MichaelBay: [Windows Storage Spaces](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12438/windows-10-storage-spaces) is pretty much a RAID, although not the usual kind (it's slab-based, while I think most RAIDs are disk-at-once)